# The difference between malloc and mmap

Tags: c, malloc, mmap

I'm Trying to implement malloc in c and I have to use mmap
but I still don't understand what is the difference between malloc and mmap (MAP_ANNON)
both of them  return a memory zone
so why we use malloc instead of mmap
what is the difference between This :

```
c = malloc(1000)
```

and this one :

```
c = mmap(NULL, 1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE| MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

Comment: Do you have any code that might explain better than this description? `mmap` isn't for memory allocation, it's for memory-mapped files. I do not know why this applies here. If you want to know exactly what it does, that's a good thing, but it's easily answered *by reading the documentation*.

Comment: If We used the MAP_ANON flag we don't need to use a file, so mmap return a memory zone but malloc return a memory zone  too what is the difference  ?

Comment: I'm not sure why that'd be the best approach vs. just making the requisite low-level OS calls that `malloc` does internally.

Comment: @tadman `mmap` is used along with potentially `sbrk` to implement `malloc` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That really depends on your operating system. Windows is notoriously weird, and there's even more strangeness in non-POSIX ones.

Comment: If you are going to use this to fetch a block of memory, I'd work on writing a proper allocator around it vs. making a whole bunch of teeny `mmap` calls.

Comment: It's funny, I'm actually just started doing my own research to write my own `malloc` clone, and I was under a similar impression as the OP. My original plan was to map a few pages using `mmap`, then figure out a way to manage memory within those pages (which is apparently what OpenBSD uses). Reading around though, `sbrk` appears to be a more common method, since apparently anonymous calls to [`mmap` aren't even standard:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20mmap(2),use%20physical%20RAM%20at%20all.)

Comment: "In this respect an anonymous mapping is similar to malloc, and is used in some malloc(3) implementations for certain allocations. However, anonymous mappings are not part of the POSIX standard, though implemented by almost all operating systems by the MAP_ANONYMOUS and MAP_ANON flags."

Comment: @Carcigenicate: On systems that don't have `MAP_ANONYMOUS` you can get the same effect by mapping `/dev/zero`.  It's just a little less efficient due to the extra system calls.

Answer (score 2):

By way of analogy, on systems that support it, `mmap()` supplies memory wholesale, while `malloc()` supplies it retail.  Because only the latter function is specified by the C Standard, code using `mmap()` will only work with systems that support it (Unix defines it, but some other operating systems don't).

Generally, a typical malloc implementation will check to see if it knows of any region of storage which has enough space available to satisfy a request.  If so, remove it will region of storage from its list of chunks, record its address for return to the caller, and--if it's significantly larger than the requested size--add the portion of the region beyond what was allocated back to its list of free regions.

If malloc() finds that none of the regions of free storage it knows about would be able to satisfy the request, it will request a region of storage from the underlying environment (likely using mmap() on a Unix system, or other means on other systems), record its address for return to the caller, and add any portion of the region beyond what's immediately needed to the list of free regions.

Note that malloc() is designed to reasonably efficiently handle a variety of scenarios, including those were an application repeatedly allocates and frees many small blocks.  Using `mmap()` for such cases would yield poor results, because it's designed to handle infrequent allocations of large blocks.  Using `malloc()` will mean that if the application requests many small regions, those requests can be satisfied by subdividing a few large regions received from `mmap()`, and also means that if an allocation frees storage and later needs to acquire some, the latter requests can reuse the storage that was just freed, without having to involve the underlying environment with such reuse.

Comment: So as i understand :
Malloc use the memory that already knows and if it's not enough it uses mmap to get more space
and the reason why we don't use mmap is that mmap always ask for a new memory space without checking if the already mapped memory has a free place
Am i Right ?

Comment: @HakimELmansouri: Many operating systems are designed to operate on chunks that are multiples of 4KiB or 64KiB of storage.  If one wanted use an OS allocation function to create 500 objects that are each 64 bytes long, those 500 objects may take up 2,048,000 bytes, of memory.  By contrast, depending upon how `malloc()` keeps track of things, the allocations could take as few as 32,000 bytes and would likely take no more than 48,000.